# Initial setup of a Spring project

Tags: eclipse, spring, gradle

I'm having trouble grasping the correct way of developing a Spring application. I'm following through the tutorial found here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I understand from reading the instructions that Gradle will download the specified dependencies, but that's only during the build phase. During the development phase, am I supposed to manually download the JAR files and include them as libraries in my Eclipse project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plugins for eclipse that will help you use gradle to develop:

http://gradle.org/tooling

Follow the link here for detailed instructions:

https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/

There's also this.  I'm not sure if they are the same plugin:

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-44

Manually loading the jars kind of defeats the purpose of using a dependency management tool.

Comment: Thanks for the links. After installing the Gradle plugin for Eclipse, I was able to make a new Gradle project, define some dependencies and then right click on the project and then Gradle > Refresh Dependencies. Running this downloaded the dependencies, and Eclipse was updated to see them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an Eclipse-based IDE, you can also use the Spring Tool Suite. It has all the required plugins to develop Spring applications with Gradle or Maven. (http://spring.io/tools/sts)